# Input to create Balanced Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Is there any input pattern of integers that is bound to produce a balanced/complete binary tree ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `a` - sorted array of inputs of length `n`.
Then lets start building BST with `a[mid]` where `mid` - middle element (`n/2`). Once we pushed `a[mid]` to BST our array is divided into 2 new sorted arrays:
a[0:mid-1] and a[mid+1, n-1].

Let's do the same logic for both of them (if sub-array is not empty): pick new `mid` element for each sub-array and push it to BST. That will produce 4 new arrays.

If we complete this process for all sub-arrays we will get most balanced BST possible for that input.

Comment: Yeah but that would mean modifying the insert function of the BST to make it add nodes in the recursive manner you mention. I was looking for an input sequence which would yield a balanced BST while making no changes to the data structure implementation.

Comment: @HaseebJaved It does not mean you have to change your insert function. You just add a function to build your BST from a sorted array. After that if you want to add another element just use the regular insert function.

Comment: @A.Sarid fair enough. But does that mean that there is no sequence patterns on its own, which when inserted in BST will yield a balanced BST i.e. without using any helper function ?

Comment: `modifying the insert function` - huh? What serhiyb describes works with a regular BST implementation.